# Integration on $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to find out the values of the following two integrals:

$1).$ $\int_{\mathbb{Q}_p}dx$

$2).$ $\int_{\mathbb{Q}_p}p^{val_p(x)}dx$,

here $dx$ is the Haar measure on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ normalized such that $\int_{\mathbb{Z}_p}dx=1$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: For 1)... Is it true that $\mathbb Q_p$ is the disjoint union of infinitely many disjoint translates of $\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: Yes it is disjoint union of $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ for all natural number $n$

Comment: So $1)$ is $\int_{p^n\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(p^n\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times})+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\mu(p^{-r}\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times})=\frac{p-1}{p}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^{-n}+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}p^r)=1+[(p-1)\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}p^r]$

Comment: So $\int_{\mathbb{Q}_p}dx$ can be seen with value in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. OK?

Comment: No, the values of Haar measure are real.  And by "translate" of a set I mean $a+\mathbb Z_p$ for some $a$.

Comment: Where did I make mistake in the computation? Is the value of 1) equal to $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, the value is $\infty$.  Haar measure of a locally compact group is finite only if the group is compact.